# Convert JSON string To Datatable/Dataset in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, json, windows-mobile

My Windows mobile application is consuming a web service while synchronizing, that return a data table from stored procedure.

I am converting this data table to JSON string and passing it to a Windows mobile application.  I want to Insert/Update the data[data Rows] from the JSON string to Mobile local database.

I want to convert JSON string to datatable and use this datable for bulk inserting or updating tables locally (can I iterate through this JSON string to insert query to insert data?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library to serialize/deserialize JSON -> Datatable/Dataset object; the library work also on compact framework.